# updating all record of a model instance using a form in django

Tags: django

I am giving my users an option to edit the records using a form. My model is very large and it will be tedious for me to update all the records one at a time. As of now I am fetching the datafields to the form's inputboxes using the Model's **id field**. How can I update all the datafields in my Model based on this **id field**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a for FormModel based on your model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

And when posting it (using POST or PUT http method) to use the FormModel to check that data is correct and update it:

```
if request.POST:
    obj_form = ObjForm(request.POST)
    if obj_form.is_valid():
        ojb = Obj.objects.get(pk=obj_id)
        ojb_form = ObjForm(request.POST, instance = obj)
        obj_form.save()
        #Do whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking to update a field [across multiple records](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) then:

```
# Update all the headlines with pub_date in 2007.
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2007).update(
    headline='Everything is the same'
)
```

Or you can use the build in generic [update view](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/) with a [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm):

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

# forms.py
class EntityForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entity

# views.py
class UpdateEntry(UpdateView):
    # See the attribute `fields` for further configuration
    form_class = EntryForm
```